# How to create simple load more in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have many words in html element i want to show 4 to 5 words and hide all word when click on more link all words will show how i can do this with javascript here is my html code

```
<dd id="hide_actors">
    <a rel="tag" href="http://link.com/archives/actors/archie-adamos">Archie Adamos</a>, 
    <a rel="tag" href="http://link.com/archives/actors/brad-johnson">Brad Johnson</a>, 
    <a rel="tag" href="http://link.com/archives/actors/eric-hahn">Eric Hahn</a>, 
    <a rel="tag" href="http://link.com/archives/actors/frederick-bailey">Frederick Bailey</a>, 
    <a rel="tag" href="http://link.com/archives/actors/jeff-griffith">Jeff Griffith</a>, 
    <a rel="tag" href="http://link.com/archives/actors/jesse-metcalfe">Jesse Metcalfe</a>, 
    <a rel="tag" href="http://link.com/archives/actors/josie-bissett">Josie Bissett</a>, 
    <a rel="tag" href="http://link.com/archives/actors/keegan-connor-tracy">Keegan Connor Tracy</a>, 
    <a rel="tag" href="http://link.com/archives/actors/ken-metcalfe">Ken Metcalfe</a>, 
    <a rel="tag" href="http://link.com/archives/actors/mark-venturini">Mark Venturini</a>, 
    <a rel="tag" href="http://link.com/archives/actors/matthew-settle">Matthew Settle</a>, 
    <a rel="tag" href="http://link.com/archives/actors/meghan-ory">Meghan Ory</a>, 
    <a rel="tag" href="http://link.com/archives/actors/rick-dean">Rick Dean</a>, 
    <a rel="tag" href="http://link.com/archives/actors/romy-diaz">Romy Diaz</a>, 
    <a rel="tag" href="http://link.com/archives/actors/ruben-ramos">Ruben Ramos</a>, 
    <a rel="tag" href="http://link.com/archives/actors/vernon-wells">Vernon Wells</a>, 
    <a rel="tag" href="http://link.com/archives/actors/virginia-madsen">Virginia Madsen</a>
</dd>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

Add new anchor to load more

```
<a href="javascript:;" id="loadmore">Load more</a>
```

**Script**

```
    $(function(){
        $('#hide_actors').find('a').each(function(index,item){
            if(index>3){
               $(item).hide();    
               $(item).next('span').hide();   
            }
        })
       $('#loadmore').click(function(){
            $('#hide_actors a').each(function(index,item){
               $(item).show();    
               $(item).next('span').show('slow');   
            })
            $('#loadmore').hide();
       });
   });
```

[**Working demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/tqsq92nb/4/)

Comment: thanks manoj superb but i have a problem with commas i don't put comma under a tag please help with that

Comment: Can you put this comma in span? @MurtazaAli

Comment: Manoj i am unable to add comma in a tag because its the wordpress function the_terms() which is rendering html and i am unable to edit it please give me a solution that comma will also hide

Comment: now my html look like this `<a rel="tag" href="http://link.com/archives/actors/archie-adamos">Archie Adamos</a><span>,</span>`

Comment: now how to tackle this span ? please help and thanks

Comment: please help me i am waiting for you

Answer (score 0):

use

**CSS**

```
#hide_actors{
    display:none;
}
```

**Javascript**

```
$(function(){
    $('#show').click(function(){
     $('#hide_actors').show('slow');
    });
});
```

[**FIDDLE DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/qecdyrpv/)